# Is there a built in way to ensure image size match per batch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a `torch.utills.data.Dataset` that returns images which slightly vary in size.

I produce my training batches using `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`. Is there an inbuilt way to resize the images such that they can be stacked into a batch on the data loader end?

If there's not, I'll probably write a `collate_fn` to do it. Or is there a better way?

PS: I don't want to resize my whole dataset to one size. That's why I'm specifically asking about doing it at a batch level.

Comment: `collate_fn` is a way to go :)

Comment: I agree with @Proko here. What your asking is not a standard operation so the easiest way to enforce this is probably a custom `collate_fn` for your `DataLoader`.

Comment: Yeah, I was 50:50 on whether there'd be something out there. I think there should be. It seems like a perfectly sensible ask.